# Pointing Bazel at a Second Directory

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, bazel

I am trying to set up the development environment for google's magenta. My problem essentially stems from the fact that I have to use a Bash emulator, such as git to run bazel.

However, you also need python, tensorflow, and other python packages, which i have all installed with anaconda.

When I try to run the bazel commands for the magenta models, I get an error saying that tensorflow is not found.

My question is what is the documentation or commands that would point bazel at the directory where anaconda(and tensorflow and the other python packages) are so that it knows to also search that directory for tensorflow/whatever it needs?

Answer (score 1):

You can tell Bazel where the Python and Bash interpreters are using the `--python_path` and `--shell_executable` flags.

With that you should be able to build py_* rules that depend on modules from the standard modules directory, whatever that is for Anaconda.

If that doesn't work, you may need to create a [`new_local_repository`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/workspace.html#new_local_repository) pointing to the modules directory.